# VSCode: Remote debugging configuration suddenly not working anymore

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm running scripts from a remote server, and usually I can debug this fine, but yesterday suddenly it won't debug anymore!

When I press the 'Start debugging' button or F5, the debugging banner appears briefly, but then disappears again and I can't restart the session otherwise I get a "There is already a debug configuration running." error.

If I subsequently run another debug config, the two of them just appears in the call stack with no way of closing/stopping/restarting them!

The way I start the session is to first ssh into the remote server with `ssh -tL 56784:localhost:56785 <remote-server> ssh -L 56785:localhost:56784 <remote-machine>` and then run the following command `python -m ptvsd --server-host 0.0.0.0 --port 56784 --wait <script>`. Usually I can then start my debugging using the following config in my launch.json:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "attach",
    "port": 56784,
    "host": "localhost",
    "pathMappings": [
        {
            "localRoot": "",
            "remoteRoot": "<path/on/remote/server>"
        }
    ]
}
```

My version of VScode is 1.33.1.

I really have no idea on how to fix this or figure out what is wrong, but hopefully someone out there can see what is wrong or have stumbled on something similar?

[ UPDATE ] 
So, I found out after some various tests that it was a problem with the vscode-python extension. Specifically, version 2019.4.12954 breaks the debugging functionality (cannot add Python debug configs for instance) and also seriously messes with the how the settings look when pressing Ctrl+Shift+P.

Rolling back to version 2019.4.11987 solves the issue, strangely enough.

Comment: So, I found out after some various tests that it was a problem with the vscode-python extension. Specifically, version 2019.4.12954 breaks the debugging functionality (cannot add Python debug configs for instance) and also seriously messes with the how the settings look when pressing Ctrl+Shift+P. Rolling back to version 2019.4.11987 solves the issue, strangely enough.

Answer (score 2):

So, I found out after some various tests that it was a problem with the vscode-python extension. Specifically, version 2019.4.12954 breaks the debugging functionality (cannot add Python debug configs for instance) and also seriously messes with the how the settings look when pressing Ctrl+Shift+P.

Rolling back to version 2019.4.11987 solves the issue, strangely enough.